# validation of form in django

Tags: django, forms, validation

i am very new in django framework.I have a template where i have a form.Simply i just want to make a validation on this form where it will check the field whether the field is empty or not.If it is empty then it will show a validation statement of something like "The required field is remain empty".Now how can i make validation? here is my form.py file

```
 from django import forms
 from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
 from request.models import Request

 class SubreqForm(forms.Form):
    request = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    sub_category = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and this is my view(you can edit the view)

```
class SubmitRequestsTemplateView(TemplateView):
template_name = "rest/submit_req.html"
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response("rest/submit_req.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and this is my template...(only the form)

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="inputText">Request</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="inputText" class="form-control" type="Text" placeholder="Request Name" ng-model="request.name"></input>
                        </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="id_category" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Category</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <select class="form-control" id="id_category" ng-model="selectedCategory" ng-options="cat.pk as cat.name for cat in category">
                                <option value="">Select Category</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="id_subcategory" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Sub-Category</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <select class="form-control" id="id_subcategory" ng-model="selectedSubCategory" ng-options="subcat.id as subcat.name for subcat in subcategory">
                            <option value="">Select SubCategory</option>
                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <center>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addRequest()">Add Request</button>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

now how can i validate my form? please help me.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: If you want to validate field empty/not empty, then just add or remove required = True to form field.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is not configured for any kind of form processing. As you have it coded, `TemplateView` will only respond to `GET` requests so when your form sends the `POST` nothing will happen.

Have a look at the generic `CreateView` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview).

Also, if you are going to manually render your form instead of having Django do it (`form.as_p`), then you will also need to [manually render any errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template) which I'm not seeing in your template above.